# Reference citation in latex block in pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, markdown, pandoc-citeproc

In my markdown document I have a complex latex table with a caption, in which I would like to add a reference.

```latex
The table can be seen below...

\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{Some complex table \protect\hyperlink{ref-doe}{(Doe et al., 2011}}
\label{tbl:complexTable}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
...
}
\end{table}

Table [@tbl:complexTable] shows...
```

With `tablenos` I am usually able to reference the paper with the `Table: Some complex table [@doe]` and when converting to pdf, the `@doe` reference is listed in the bibliography chapter. **However since the reference is inside the latex block, it doesn't show in the bibliography chapter. How do I solve this?**

Comment: In LaTeX part of a markdown you can use only Latex commands. Insert anywhere in the markdown part `[@doe]` and check  how it is exported to LaTeX exactly (e.g., some like  `\autocite{doe}`, but it depends on what citation method are you using.) This this is the code that you must use inside the `\caption{}`.

Comment: @Fran Thank you for your response. The Late output of `[@doe] is in fact `\protect\hyperlink{ref-doe}{(Doe et al., 2011}}`, however putting it there with the `\hyperlink...` does not make it appear in the Bibliography chapter. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
---
format: pdf
link-citations: true
references:
- type: article-journal
  id: doe
  author:
  - family: Doe
    given: D. D.
  issued:
    year: 2011 
  title: 'Very foo and too munch foo'
  container-title: Journal of Foo
  volume: 171
  issue: 2
  page: 737--778
nocite: | 
  @doe  
---

The table can be seen below...

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Some complex table \protect\hyperlink{ref-doe}{(Doe, 2011)}}
\label{tbl-complexTable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline x\\\hline\end{tabular}   
\end{table}

<!-- A @doe markdown cite. -->

### References

::: {#refs}
:::
```

If you are exporting references with `citeproc`, the references are added as text in the LaTeX export,  and in citations are just hyperlinks to items. There are not true citation commands to be processed by bibtex or biber programs.

From the markdown point of view, the LaTeX parts do not exist, and therefore if there are not any `@doe` in the markdown side, there are nothing to link and nothing to be referenced. In the LaTeX part you  add a link to nowhere, not a command  to include a cite and a reference. There are at least three ways to surpass this problem:

One could be simply add  `@doe` or `[@doe]` somewhere  in the markdown part. This will make the target, so the link to nowhere will work now. The only problem could be that you do not want other link  except that of the caption. In the example, this "extra cite" is deactivated in a HTML comment. If you want to test it, turn the HTML comment in plain text, and remove the `nocite` directive, that is the second method:

Use `nocite` in the YAML header you cab include references that you do not what to mention in text. This will create the target  without the link, but you provide it in the LaTeX code. To test it, run the example "as is".

The third way is to use `natbib`  or `biblatex` citation methods. In this case, list the references and format the cite is an external business for bibtex or biber programs, and pandoc just washes his hands. You will need the references in bibtex (.bib) format, and specify the citation method, adding in the YAML header at least:

```
bibliography: references.bib # or  whatever.bib 
citation-method: natbib      # or biblatex (default is citeproc)
```

The natbib and biblatex methods will leave `@doe` or `[@doe]` as a true LaTeX citation command (not just a hyperlink) and also some  LaTeX commands at end of the document to print the references, so you cannot read the text of the references in the exported LaTeX code, but in the PDF only. That is,  instead of be export the cite as `\protect\hyperlink{target}{text}` leave it as a true citation command, e.g., \textcite{doe} or \autocite{doe} (depending of the cite style,  and the `citation-method`). The commands generated in each case in main markdown text is what you must translate to the table caption manually, and they will make the cite and the  reference even if there are not  `@doe` in markdown text or `nocite` in the header.

Note: sometimes is not clear for pandoc what is markdown  and  what is another markup language that should not be touched. It is always better to enclose the LaTeX part in this way:

````
```{=latex}

\begin{whatever}
\end{whatever} 

```
````